# Delphi, Android, SSL - IdSMTP ConnectTimeout - after preset timeout does not terminate connection to the server

Tags: android, delphi, openssl, indy10, delphi-10.2-tokyo

When I set ConnectTimeout at IdSMTP (for example, 30 sec) and the SMTP server is unavailable, it takes off from the SMTP server approximately 105 sec.

This is the Indy component in version 10 - *250.bpl, OpenSSL v1.0.2.

With IdFTP ConnectTimeout work without any problems.

Where may be a bug?

```
...
IdOpenSSLSetLibPath(FDocumentsPath);

SSLHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
SMTP:= TIdSMTP.Create(nil);
MSG:= TIdMessage.Create(nil);

try
  SSLHandler.SSLOptions.Method:= sslvSSLv23;
  SSLHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;

  SMTP.IOHandler := SSLHandler;
  SMTP.UseTLS:= utUseImplicitTLS;
  SMTP.AuthType:= satDefault;

  SMTP.Port:= 465;
  SMTP.Host:= xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
  SMTP.Username:= xxxxx;
  SMTP.Password:= xxxxx;

  SMTP.ConnectTimeout:= 30000;
  SMTP.ReadTimeout:= 30000;

  try
    SMTP.Connect;
  except
  end;

  ...
finally
  SMTP.Disconnect;
  UnLoadOpenSSLLibrary;

  FreeAndNil(MSG);
  FreeAndNil(SSLHandler);
  FreeAndNil(SMTP);
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ConnectTimeout` is implemented by `TIdIOHandlerStack` and so applies equally to all TCP client components (IOW, `TIdFTP` and `TIdSMTP` use the exact same timeout logic).

However, you have to take into account that `ConnectTimeout` only applies to the actual connection attempt (the call to the socket API `connect()` function). It does not apply to the time needed to resolve a hostname to an IP address, or to the time needed to create and tear down the worker thread that performs the actual connection while the timeout is monitored.  So `ConnectTimeout` is not exact.

A 30 sec timeout taking 105 sec could mean DNS is taking a long time to resolve the hostname, or it could mean the socket API is not aborting the `connect()` call in a timely manner once the timeout has elapsed.  Debug the code to see where the time is actually being spent.  Check the `OnStatus` event to see how much time elapses between the `hsResolving` and `hsConnecting` notifications, and between the `hsConnecting` notification and subsequent exception when the socket fails to connect to the server.

Comment: Well explained. Thanks Remy

Comment: how to add to onStatus ?

Comment: @FZs how to add WHAT to OnStatus? Please be more specific.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i mean is it just add this line in event IdSMTP1Status --> Memo1.Lines.Add('IdSMTP1Status : '+FormatDatetime('hhnnss',now)+' '+AStatusText); to see how much time elapses ?

Comment: @FZS you could do it that way, yes. I would suggest including milliseconds in the output, though. Also, this is adding UI delays to the times. To avoid that, you could save the times to a `TDateTime[]` array first and then display the array values after `Connect()` is finished. Also, you might consider using `TStopWatch` instead of `TDateTime` for more accuracy.